# Сбрасывается статическая переменная в классе при обновлении страницы PHP

Tags: php, mvc, static

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь передать соединение с БД между двумя страницами. Соединение передается в контроллер через переменную сессии. Соединение успешно функционирует до того момента, когда пользователь обновляет страницу во **второй** раз. После второго обновления страницы статическая переменная `$instance` начинает возвращать NULL. Как сохранить её значение, независимо от количества перезагрузок страницы?

```
<?php
class Controller_upload extends Controller
{   

private static
    $instance = null;   

function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new Model_Upload();
    $this->view = new View(); 
    self::$instance=$_SESSION['dbase_conn'];    
}



 public static function getInstance()
{

    if (null === self::$instance)
    {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

private function __clone() {}

function action_index()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['dbase_conn']))
    {
    unset($_SESSION['dbase_conn']);

    }
    $data=self::$instance;
    $this->view->generate('upload_view.php', 'upload_template_view.php',$data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Машина времени нас перенесла в середину 200х годов :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через сессию можно передавать только сериализуемые значения, соединение с СУБД в стандартных расширениях является несериализуемым значением типа resource и передавать через сессию или иным способом между двумя запросами нельзя. Есть понятие постоянного соединения, разделяемого между несколькими обработчиками, но привязки к сессиии там точно нет.

Answer (score 1):

Соединение с БД всегда разрывается при завершении PHP скрипта.

Соединение с БД надо устанавливать в начале PHP скрипта.

В сессии стоит сохранять только то что к пользователю относится и должно сохраняться между запросами пользователя.

И код бредовый какой-то: в $instance  записывается и `$_SESSION['dbase_conn']` и `new self()`.

Answer (score -3):

Никак. Тут вам даже pconnect не поможет.
Пересматривайте логику вашего алгоритма.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?